# image left and right for dynamic content width

Tags: html, css

I have a main content div with the following css

```
width: 80%;
max-width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 1px solid black
```

Now I want to place a background images / a div on either side of my contextbox that stays fixed on the page and is clipped by the page. The purpose is to add a image that shows left and right.

It should look somewhat like this:

```
              ------------------
              |                |
           ---|                |---
           |  |      Main      |  |
           |  |    Content     |  |
           |  |                |  |

            ^                    ^
             \--------------------\- Should these two side containers reach outside of the viewport they should be cliped. Also these should have a fixed position.
```

Can this be achieved with pure css (without Javascript)? Or could it be achieved with pure css if I am willing to give up on the variable main content width?

Comment: you didn't explain how wide (10% or take the remaining space?) should your aside DIV be, and also some HTML and CSS of your best try!

Comment: [jsBin example](http://jsbin.com/hoyuxu/2/)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: the example gets surprisingly close, but it is slightly more complicated: the side divs should have a fixed size. Also in your case the images slide under the middle content when the viewframe becomes smaller.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan As for my best try: adding divs as float, however this caused issues: since i had the floating divs I needed to center the content. I tried wrapping the three divs in another element, however that eliminated the possibility to use the percentual width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="main">
 <div class="left"></div>
 <div class="right"></div>
</div>

.main{
 position: relative;
 width: 80%;
 max-width: 800px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 1px solid black
}
.left{
 position: absolute;
 right: 100%;
 width: 12.5%;
  height 100%;
}
.right{
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 12.5%;
  height 100%;
}
```

something like that should work what you need to know is that :
* children positioned element width and height in % take their first positioned parent 
dimension when 100%.
* i haven't tested, try playing with the numbers ;-)

Comment: While this works rather nice, the left and right elements scroll with the main content. I would like left and right to be fixed in the view port.

Comment: so position in fixed but your width will be related to the window i guess